# Using Meteor with cordova.plugins.diagnostic not Work

Tags: meteor, cordova-plugins, diagnostics

I'm using METEOR@1.4.2.3 with following Plugins:

```
cordova:cordova-plugin-backbutton       0.3.0
cordova:cordova-plugin-camera           2.1.1
cordova:cordova-plugin-device           1.1.4
cordova:cordova-plugin-sim              1.3.2
cordova:cordova.plugins.diagnostic      2.3.16
cordova:phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner  3.0.0
```

I try to implement new right structure for Android API Level 26  (from API Level 22 to 26) and it doesn't work.

**Code**:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
console.log(device.cordova);

  cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestRuntimePermissions(function(statuses) {
    for (var permission in statuses) {
        switch (statuses[permission]) {
            case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED:
                console.log("Permission granted to use " + permission);
                break;
            case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.NOT_REQUESTED:
                console.log("Permission to use " + permission + " has not been requested yet");
                break;
            case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.DENIED:
                console.log("Permission denied to use " + permission + " - ask again?");
                break;
            case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.DENIED_ALWAYS:
                console.log("Permission permanently denied to use " + permission + " - guess we won't be using it then!");
                break;
        }
    }
}, function(error) {
    console.error("The following error occurred: " + error);
}, [
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permission.CAMERA,
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
  ]);

}
```

I always get this error and APP is frozen:

> I20180831-10:52:52.483(2)? 08-31 10:52:44.612 29275 29275 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5283)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'CAMERA' of undefined", source: http://localhost:12136/app/app.js?hash=4b27536f027d34508de1ae9fccb904c97e426df1 (5283)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

An error message like this

> Cannot read property 'CAMERA' of undefined"

Serves to tell you to look in your code for where there is a `.CAMERA`, which is this line:

`cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permission.CAMERA,`

Which means that `cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permission` is not defined. It means that `cordova.plugins.diagnostic` is defined, so you need to check the documentation for that plugin.

That will tell you where to look, and the next piece of advice is to write defensive code to allow for the unexpected. Something like this:

```
if (cordova && cordova.plugins && cordova.plugins.diagnostic && cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permission) {
  // Everything is defined, expect cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permission.CAMERA to be valid
} else {
  console.error("Something undefined in cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permission") 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the problem.

I'm adding Plugin

```
cordova:cordova-plugin-android-permissions  1.0.0
```

to the project.

The modified Function OnDeviceReady:

```
 function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log(device.cordova);

    var permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions;

   permissions.checkPermission(permissions.READ_PHONE_STATE, function( status ){
      if ( status.hasPermission ) {
        console.log("Yes (READ_PHONE_STATE) ");
      }
      else {
        console.warn("No (READ_PHONE_STATE) ");
        permissions.requestPermission(permissions.READ_PHONE_STATE, success, error('READ_PHONE_STATE'));
      }
    });

    permissions.checkPermission(permissions.CAMERA, function( status ){
      if ( status.hasPermission ) {
        console.log("Yes (CAMERA) ");
      }
      else {
        console.warn("No (CAMERA) ");
        permissions.requestPermission(permissions.CAMERA, success, error("CAMERA"));
      }
    });

    permissions.checkPermission(permissions.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, function( status ){
      if ( status.hasPermission ) {
        console.log("Yes (WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ");
      }
      else {
        console.warn("No (WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ");   
        permissions.requestPermission(permissions.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
        success,error("WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")
          );
      }
    });

    permissions.checkPermission(permissions.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, function( status ){
      if ( status.hasPermission ) {
        console.log("Yes (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ");
      }
      else {
        console.warn("No (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ");
        permissions.requestPermission(permissions.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, success, error('READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'));
      }
    });

    function error(permission4request) {
        console.warn(permission4request + ' permission is not turned on');
        console.log(permission4request + ' permission is not turned on');
    }
     fdsf

    function success( status ) {
        if( !status.hasPermission ) error();
    }

    loginLogic();
}
```

This Code works with API Level 26 to request permissions.